# resample and groupby, mean and sum

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

this is my input dataframe

```
d1 = pd.Timestamp(2020,8,1)
d2 = pd.Timestamp(2020,9,1)
somedict = {'a':[2,3,2,3,4], 'b':['one','two','two','two','one'], 'c':['yes','no','yes','yes','no'] ,'d':[d1,d1,d2,d1,d2], 'e':[8,7,7,6,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(somedict)
df.set_index('d',inplace=True)
```

i would like to group it by column `b` using `df.groupby('b')`, and resample by month using `df.resample('M')`. after grouping and resampling, i would like to see two things

1. how many instances of `yes` we have in column `c`
2. take the sum of column `a`, divided by the sum of column `e`

so the resulting output should be grouped by the categories `one, two` from column `b`, and the sums/number of instances should be shown per month

i've tried to run `(df['c'] == 'yes').resample('M').mean()` which almost answers question 1, but since `b` is no longer a part of the result, i can't write `groupby('b')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
groups = df.groupby(['b',pd.Grouper(freq='M')])

out = pd.DataFrame({'count_c': groups['c'].apply(lambda x: x.eq('yes').sum()),
                    'a/e': groups['a'].sum()/groups['e'].sum()
                   })
```

Output:

```
                count_c       a/e
b   d                            
one 2020-08-31        1  0.250000
    2020-09-30        0  0.444444
two 2020-08-31        1  0.461538
    2020-09-30        1  0.285714
```

Alternatively, you could bypass the `apply` function and use a pipe instead (with a slight speed increase):

```
(df.assign(c=lambda df: df['c'].map({"yes":1,"no":0}))
   .groupby(['b', pd.Grouper(freq='M')])
   .pipe(lambda df: pd.DataFrame({"count_c": df['c'].sum(), 
                                  "a/e": df['a'].sum()/df['e'].sum()}))
 )
 
                count_c       a/e
b   d                            
one 2020-08-31        1  0.250000
    2020-09-30        0  0.444444
two 2020-08-31        1  0.461538
    2020-09-30        1  0.285714
```

Comment: thanks! i had not seen the `Grouper` before, if you have any good tutorial/documentation i'd definitely check it out to understand it a bit better

Comment: I think the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) is a pretty good start.

Comment: Added an alternative @QuangHoang; if that's ok with you. did not feel different enough to warrant a separate post